# How to execute parallel REST API calls in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, intentservice, background-service

Hi I am developing android application. My application contains REST API calls for fetching data from server. So my application requirements are like this:

consider I have 2 REST API calls all are independent; That mean both are not dependent on each  other; So I want parallel execution. Result of both API calls associated with two different activities.

I want to run both network calls in background. Don't want to execute on UI thread.

I am confuse with following few solutions:
use separate async task for each network call. What happen if I execute 10 calls parallel with async task?

Use intent service: Will intent service is good solution for handling multiple network calls parallel in background.

How to handle this in proper way. Need good solution for this. Need help. Thank you.

Comment: Hi stacks thank you for quick replay. If I want to run 10 network calls then i have to use 10 syanc task right? Whether it will affect my application and application Ui?

Comment: i dont think u should use that number of asyncTask but wont affect the  UI

Comment: @nilkash: You can use one AsyncTask for all API call and response back to Activity or anywhere else using interface

Comment: @jayesh thank you for replay. If I run 4 ask task at a time will they run parallel or not ?

Comment: @nilkash: yes , they will run parallel

Answer (score 3):

Executing on 2 AsyncTasks will work.  However, on Android versions 3.0 or higher you need to call task.executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params) instead of execute.  If you don't do that, the 3.0 implementation of AsyncTask only runs 1 task at a time serially.  If you do this it uses a pool of about 5 threads to run them.

Comment: Thank you Gabe sechan for help. I have one more question question why we can not use intent service? Mean difference between both. Thank you for help

Comment: Well, IntentService works serially-  it does one request then another.  So it won't work if you want to run them in parallel.  Other than that you can do it with an IntentService, its really a matter of preference.

Comment: So async task create new threads for new requests but intent service work on same thread that's why it is serial am i right?

Comment: Right.  Just remember that AsyncTask needs that executeOnExecutor call on 3.0+ or it will do things serially too.